# deploying webapp on domain name

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat6

I'm going to deploy a web application on tomcat 6. my host is like this:

```
  <Host name="demo.domainName.com"  appBase="webapps/site"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="demo_trace_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
  </Host>
```

I want go to site by demo.domainName.com but this does not work for me. 

I have to use below host:

```
  <Host name="demo.domainName.com"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="demo_trace_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
  </Host>
```

and go to site by demo.domainName.com/site

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Define “does not work”; i.e., what happens instead?

Comment: It brings empty page (white page).

Comment: This question belongs on [webmasters.se]

Comment: Do you have your DNS (or /etc/hosts file) set up to correctly resolve `demo.domainname.com` to the server's IP address?

Comment: I want to remote /site from end of domain name.